# SQL statement to remove parts of a string

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a database table with a list of tweets (text) from twitter. Some of these tweets mention URL links and other users with the format @usernameOfOtherUser.

I'm attempting to get rid of these links and @username's from the table. So for example, instead of having the following:

> "@michael I had a good day today http://link.com/22"

It can look more like this in the database:

> "I had a good day today"

I've tried using the REPLACE function `REPLACE(REPLACE(tweets, '@', ''), 'http://', '')` but it ends up getting rid of the entire text rather than just the specific usernames and links. Is there a solution to this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: "REGEXP_REPLACE was introduced in MariaDB 10.0.5". I'm not sure if this function is even planned for MySQL-Server.

Comment: Most likely have to end up pulling clumps from the db into php, and processing and updating the rows one by one. _IF_ this is just a one time cleanup, then thats not a big deal. But if its to do this always... not so good.

Comment: Hey @Randall unfortunately I'll be doing a lot of cleanup as I have A LOT of data to collect.

Comment: You can write a `REPLACE`  query using `LOCATE` if you have *just one* occurrence of `'@'` and `'http://'` per record.

Comment: @SterlingKing Understood. I've done a lot of converting/cleaning over the years on old databases with millions of records. Rarely finding a "all in one sql query" for most of them (especially cleanup like you have). I've always just resorted to a php script. If its a cleanup I run often, I stuff it into the daily cronjob. Those scripts usually take anywhere from 2-60 seconds to run through lol. So long as you key your tables right, its manageable.

Comment: @Randall Ok no problem, since I'm not very experienced with cleanups in MySQL databases using PHPMyAdmin, could you help by writing a quick guide on how to do that? I'll select it as the answer for this question. Regardless, I appreciate your help. Thanks!